# HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() freezes execution/doesn't time out

Tags: android, authorization, cpanel, httpurlconnection

I'm writing an Android app that connects to a cPanel server (Apache 2.2.22) page which is password protected. When the authentication credentials are correct, I have no problem connecting. However, when the credentials are incorrect, my Android application seems to freeze in the `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` method. The logs on the server show hundreds of requests being sent from my Android device, all returning a 401 as expected, but for some reason this is not reflected in my application.

Here is my code, executed from within an AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... bookInfoString) {
        // Stop if cancelled
        if(isCancelled()){
            return null;
        }
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "SendToDatabase.doInBackground()");

        String apiUrlString = getResources().getString(R.string.url_vages_library);
        try{
            NetworkConnection connection = new NetworkConnection(apiUrlString);
            connection.appendPostData(bookInfoString[0]);
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "responseCode: " + responseCode);
            return responseCode;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

This code makes use of my own class `NetworkConnection`, which is just a basic wrapper class around an HttpURLConnection, to avoid repeating code. Here it is:

```
public class NetworkConnection {

    private String url;
    private HttpURLConnection connection;

    public NetworkConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Building NetworkConnection for the URL \"" + urlString + "\"");

        url = urlString;
        // Build Connection.
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(1000 /* 1 seconds */);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000 /* 1 seconds */);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // Impossible: The only two URLs used in the app are taken from string resources.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // Impossible: "GET" is a perfectly valid request method.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void appendPostData(String postData) {

        try{
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "appendPostData() called.\n" + postData);

            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "connection.getConnectTimeout(): " + connection.getConnectTimeout());
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "connection.getReadTimeout(): " + connection.getReadTimeout());

            // Modify connection settings.
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // Get OutputStream and attach POST data.
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            writer.write(postData);
            if(writer != null){
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Connection timed out.");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // Impossible: "POST" is a perfectly valid request method.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // Impossible: "UTF-8" is a perfectly valid encoding.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Pretty sure this is impossible but not 100%.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getResponseCode() throws IOException{
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "getResponseCode()");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "responseCode: " + responseCode);
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void disconnect(){
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "disconnect()");
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

And finally, here is a fraction of the logcat logs:

```
05-03 11:01:16.315: D/vages.library.NetworkConnection(3408): connection.getConnectTimeout(): 1000
05-03 11:01:16.315: D/vages.library.NetworkConnection(3408): connection.getReadTimeout(): 1000
05-03 11:01:16.585: I/vages.library.NetworkConnection(3408): getResponseCode()
05-03 11:04:06.395: I/vages.library.MainActivity$SendToDatabase(3408): SendToDatabase.onPostExecute(null)
```

You can see the the method seems to just return null after a random amount of time. The longest I have waited was exactly 15 minutes. There are also several memory logs (GC_CONCURRENT) from dalikvm between the last two info logs which I have omitted.

I should also say that at the moment I am not using https, although I do not believe that should cause any problems. I would be very grateful for any feedback with this, whether it's a complete answer or just a comment telling me what **isn't** the problem, as I am still unsure whether this problem is server-side or client-side.

Thank you very much,
William

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention before, I am attaching my authentication credentials with my own custom `java.net.Authenticator`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    Context mContext;

    public CustomAuthenticator(Context context){
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String username = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_USERNAME_PREFERENCE, null);
        String password = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PASSWORD_PREFERENCE, null);

        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

which I set in the activity's`onCreate()` method:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator(mContext));
```

Also, I have used curl to request the password protected resource, and have received a 401 as expected. I am now assuming the problem is client-side.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm blind but I cannot see right now where do you send your auth credentials. Anyway, maybe you can try the request using curl to see what kind of output do you get: `curl -v "http://yoururl.com" -u user:password`. If it doesn't work the problem will probably be in the server side.

Comment: Thanks @Esparver, I've tried it in curl and it's returning a 401 as expected. So I guess it's a client-side problem then.

I am sending my auth credentials using a java.net.Authenticator. I'll attach this code to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4326) with using Authenticator in POST connections. It's quite old so I don't know if it still exists.

I would try two things:

- Add a log line in the `getPasswordAuthentication` of the `Authenticator` to see if it's effectively called. If nothing is printed, you should check that you add the default `Authenticator` before it's called. You say you do it in the `onCreate()`, so it should be fine but it's good to be sure.
- Avoid using the Authenticator (at least for testing purposes) and send the auth info directly in the HTTP Request. I usually do it this way:

  ```
  String auth = user + ":" + pass;
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", 
                 "Basic " + Base64.encode(auth.getBytes()));
  // Set other parameters and read the result...
  ```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I put a log in `getPasswordAuthentication` and it's being called multiple times. It made me realise that a 401 is given when the request has no Authorization header **and** when the details are incorrect, so my app is automatically sending more requests with faulty auth credentials. According to REST, it is the client who should handle this, so I have put a retry counter in my `CustomAuthenticator`. It now works and I will post my answer, although I am still looking for alternatives.

Comment: Using `HttpURLConneciton.setRequestProperty()` was actually how I was authenticating before. It works perfectly on devices running 3.0+, but for some reason on 2.3.4 and below, I am receiving 400s whether the credentials are correct or not, and the server logs don't record the request at all. I am still searching for an answer to this problem as well so would appreciate anything else you can suggest, although I may create a new question for it. I now have a workaround for this question, but I am still seeking knowledge and a real solution.

Comment: I ran into the same problem when using the `Authenticator` with `PUT` requests. I'm going to change my `Authenticator` to give the user a chance to reenter the credentials or cancel the action altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the `401 Unauthorized` status is sent when the `Authorization` header is missing *and* when the credentials contained within the header are incorrect. Therefore, my app was constantly sending the same request over and over to no avail. I have therefore found a workaround to the problem by adding a counter into my `CustomAuthenticator`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    public static int RETRIES = 3;

    int mRetriesLeft;
    Context mContext;

    public CustomAuthenticator(Context context){
        super();
        mRetriesLeft = RETRIES;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "getPasswordAuthentication() - mCounter: " + mRetriesLeft);

        if(mRetriesLeft > 0){       

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            String username = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_USERNAME_PREFERENCE, null);
            String password = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PASSWORD_PREFERENCE, null);

            mRetriesLeft--;
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

        } else {
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "No more retries. Returning null");
            mRetriesLeft = RETRIES;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void reset(){
        mRetriesLeft = RETRIES;
    }
}
```

I should say however that I do not like this solution and therefore, have not accepted it. You have to remember to reset the counter whenever you make a new request (I do it in `AsyncTask.onPreExecute()`), or else every third request will fail. Also, I'm sure there must be a native way to do this, although after scouring the documentation I can't find it. I would still be very grateful if anyone can point it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am right or not but my solution has worked for me for a whole day without a glitch.

Try doing this

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
Inputstream is;
do
{
    http conn code etc;
    is=conn.getInputStream();

    if(is.read(buf)==0)             
    {
        flag=1;
    }

    //u can either is.close(); or leave as is

    //code

    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();     
    conn.disconnect();

} while(flag==1);
```